# How do I safely re-install a corrupt Docker-desktop installation on Windows 11 without losing containers and data (due to Docker failed to initialize)

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

To solve the issue described in detail below, I would like to know: if I re-install Docker desktop in the same folders, will my existing images, containers and data contents be retained or lost?

If so, is there a way to re-install it (to fix a corruption) without loosing them?

```
Windows version: 11 Home v 21H2, OS build 22000.856
Docker version: Docker 4.11.1
```

---

I've been using Docker for my local development for about 6 months now and it has been great: docker-compose to spin up containers for NGINX, PHP, MySQL.

An error suddenly developed yesterday wherein it no longer starts up, gives the error:

```
Docker failed to initialize: Docker Desktop is shutting down.
```

The most recurring solution from googling is to delete:

```
....\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json
```

Before deleting, I did observe that the file was corrupted. Now rebooting the system according to those googled guides, should not let it boot up correctly but same error all the time. I have also tried stopping and starting the service manually to no avail.

Looking into Event viewer, Windows Log - Application, it shows even though the Docker service started successfully, it has an Event ID of 0 which seems to mean there is a corruption.

I also just discovered my restore point flag wasn't on so I'm unable to revert to the state of the system before this corruption occurred.

Answer (score 2):

A search for "docker-desktop error log location" showed me where to find the logs. For my Windows 11 set up, this was at

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host
```

There I found:

```
[com.docker.backend.exe][E] writing locks to locked-directories: reading <HOME>\AppData\Roaming\Docker\locked-directories: parsing JSON from <HOME>\AppData\Roaming\Docker\locked-directories: invalid character '\x00' looking for beginning of value
```

The file (locked-directories) was corrupted and couldn't be opened with a text editor.

Deleting it and restarting resolved without re-installation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).